# is List badly performing in python?

Tags: python

I was trying to read data from some huge file and write them back, but I realised that the main cost came from assigning data to a list rather then reading or writing data from/to file....

```
    rows = [None] * 1446311
    begin = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in range( 1446311 ):
       row = csvReader.next()
       rows[i] = row
    print datetime.datetime.now() - begin
```

above code is taking 18 sec but 5 sec if I comment out line 5 (`rows[i] = row`), I have build the list in advance (i.e. reserve the memory) but why it is still so slow? anything I could do the make it faster? I tried `row for row in csvReader` but it performs worse...

regards,
John

Comment: I see no big difference in the runtime between L5 being there and not being there. (I had to fake the csvReader.next() call, though, which may have an impact.)

Comment: As Gareth explains, you are not preallocating the memory for all the actual rows and this allocation is what is taking the time. If you do not require all the rows to be in memory at the same time, you may get a performance increase by structuring your code to use generators/generator expressions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get similar results, but not quite so dramatic as yours. (Note the use of the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module for timing code execution, and note that I've factored out the list creation since its common to both test cases.)

```
import csv
from timeit import Timer

def write_csv(f, n):
    """Write n records to the file named f."""
    w = csv.writer(open(f, 'wb'))
    for i in xrange(n):
        w.writerow((i, "squared", "equals", i**2))

def test1(rows, f, n):
    for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(open(f))):
        rows[i] = r

def test2(rows, f, n):
    for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(open(f))):
        pass

def test(t): 
    return (Timer('test%d(rows, F, N)' % t,
                  'from __main__ import test%d, F, N; rows = [None] * N' % t)
            .timeit(number=1))

>>> N = 1446311
>>> F = "test.csv"
>>> write_csv(F, N)
>>> test(1)
2.2321770191192627
>>> test(2)
1.7048690319061279
```

Here's my guess as to what is going on. In both tests, the CSV reader reads a record from the file and creates a data structure in memory representing that record.

In `test2`, where the record is not stored, the data structure gets deleted more or less immediately (on the next iteration of the loop, the `row` variable is updated, so the reference count of the previous record is decremented, and so the memory is reclaimed). This makes the memory used for the previous record available for reuse: this memory is already in the computer's virtual memory tables, and probably still in the cache, so it's (relatively) fast.

In `test1`, where the record is stored, each record has to be allocated in a new region of memory, which has to be allocated by the operating system, and copied to the cache, so it's (relatively) slow.

So the time is not taken up by *list assignment*, but by *memory allocation*.

---

Here are another couple of tests that illustrate what's going on, without the complicating factor of the `csv` module. In `test3` we create a new 100-element list for each row, and store it. In `test4` we create a new 100-element list for each row, but we don't store it, we throw it away so that the memory can be reused on the next time round the loop.

```
def test3(rows, f, n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        rows[i] = [i] * 100

def test4(rows, f, n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        temp = [i] * 100
        rows[i] = None

>>> test(3)
9.2103338241577148
>>> test(4)
1.5666921138763428
```

So I think the lesson is that if you do not need to store all the rows in memory at the same time, don't do that! If you can, read them in one at a time, process them one at a time, and then forget about them so that Python can deallocate them.

Comment: you mentioned the time was taken from memory allocation, did you mean for memory for the list content or the reference (pointer) for the list? both test3 and test4 only allocate memory for the list content i.e. [i] * 100 once I think?

Comment: I mean memory for all the rows. Also, tests 3 and 4 allocate a new 100-element list *each time* round the loop.

Comment: and also, you said the next loop could take advantage from the memory we allocated from previous loop, why these memory would be different to other 'wild' but free memory block? as we have de-reference the previous allocated memory, right?

Comment: Deallocated memory is not the same as "wild" (never allocated) memory! "Wild" memory needs to be allocated by the operating system (page tables etc) and then cached; recently deallocated memory does not.

Comment: yes, I missed that, it is still faster even the size of memory required by the next loop might be bigger than the previous one as Python might somehow delay the 'uncaching' of de-referenced memory. as you mentioned, memory allocation is not cheap in Python. As as new python programmer, I think I should read some materials about memory management in Python, Python is not designed for performance critical software though.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this first part is not so valid (see comments below)

Did you make a try like this:

```
rows = [None] * 1446311
for i in range( 1446311 ):
   rows[i] = csvReader.next()
```

Because from what I see in your code, you're copying the data twice: one from file to memory with `row = ...`, and once from `row` to `rows[i]`. As you have non-mutable things here (strings), we really are talking about copy of data, not about copy of references.

Moreover, even if you created an empty list before, you put big piece of data inside; as you only put `None` in the beginning, no real memory space has been reserved. So maybe you could as well write directly a very simple thing like this:

```
rows = []
for i in range( 1446311 ):
   rows.append(csvReader.next())
```

or maybe even use the generator syntax directly!

```
rows = list(csvReader)
```

---

EDIT
After reading Gareth's answer, I did some time-testing on my proposals. By the way, take care to put some protection when reading from an iterator, in order to stop nicely if the iterator is shorter than expected:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> import csv
>>> # building some timing framework:
>>> def test(n):
    return min(Timer('test%d(F, N)' % t,
                  'from __main__ import test%d, F, N' % t)
            .repeat(repeat=10, number=1))

>>> F = r"some\big\csvfile.csv"
>>> N = 200000
>>> def test1(file_in, number_of_lines):
    csvReader = csv.reader(open(file_in, 'rb'))
    rows = [None] * number_of_lines
    for i, c in enumerate(csvReader):  # using iterator syntax
        if i > number_of_lines:  # and limiting the number of lines
            break
        row = c
        rows[i] = row
    return rows

>>> test(1)
0.31833305864660133

>>> def test2(file_in, number_of_lines):
    csvReader = csv.reader(open(file_in, 'rb'))
    rows = [None] * number_of_lines
    for i, c in enumerate(csvReader):
        if i > number_of_lines:
            break
        row = c
    return rows

>>> test(2)
0.25134269758603978  # remember that only last line is stored!

>>> def test3(file_in, number_of_lines):
    csvReader = csv.reader(open(file_in, 'rb'))
    rows = [None] * number_of_lines
    for i, c in enumerate(csvReader):
        if i > number_of_lines:
            break
        rows[i] = c
    return rows

>>> test(3)
0.30860502255637812

>>> def test4(file_in, number_of_lines):
    csvReader = csv.reader(open(file_in, 'rb'))
    rows = []
    for i, c in enumerate(csvReader):
        if i > number_of_lines:
            break
        rows.append(c)
    return rows

>>> test(4)
0.32001576256431008

>>> def test5(file_in, number_of_lines):
    csvReader = csv.reader(open(file_in, 'rb'))
    rows = list(csvReader)  
    # problem: there's no way to limit the number of lines to parse!
    return rows

>>> test(5)
0.30347613834584308
```

What we can see, for a N greater than the number of lines in the document, no great difference in timing. `test2` is, on my machine, unexpectingly only a little different. `test5` is more elegant, but cannot limit the number of lines parsed, which can be annoying.

So, if you need all lines at once, my advice would be to go to the most elegant solution, even if a bit longer: `test4`. But maybe, as Gareth's ask, you do not need everything at once, which is the best way to gain speed and memory.

Comment: Did you try any of these suggestions to see if they made any difference to the run time?

Comment: I did it after reading Gareth's answer. Please see edit in my answer.

Comment: @Gareth oh sorry, I missed that it was you that were asking for some more material. Sorry for the delay in the answer, I took time for formatting.

Comment: There are still a couple of mistakes near the top: "you're copying the data twice" and some confusion about mutable vs non-mutable objects. Otherwise, looks good.

Comment: Oh I see: I did not have in mind that `csv` module was returning a list of values for each line. So that's correct, the beginning of my answer is a bit out of topic. By the way, wouldn't `test1` be returning a list of references, all pointing to the last `row` list parsed by the csvReader?